# XPath -> Selecting element with class attribute

Tags: php, xpath, scraper

I want to get all organic search results from Google.

I need help defining the XPath to exclude the ads. The cite tag on the ads does not contain a class attribute, and the organic results have 2 different class values. My attempts at defining the XPath have failed. The Google results page looks something like this

```
Ad
<cite>example.com</cite> 

Organic Result 1 
<cite class="_Rm">example.com/page1.html</cite> 

Organic Result 2
<cite class="_Rm bc">example.com > Breadcrumbs > Page2</cite>
```

Here is my code:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.google.com/search?q=mortgage&num=100');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//cite');

foreach ($nodes as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue.'<br />'; // Show all links
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try `//cite[@class='_Rm' or @class='_Rm bc']` This will select `cite` nodes with a class that is either `_Rm` or `_RM bc`.

Comment: That's not returning any results for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the portion of the HTML you want to get is not generated by client-side scripts (usually javascript), following simple XPath will do the job :

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//cite[@class]');
```

Above XPath gets all `<cite>` tags containing class attribute with any value.

Otherwise, you need to *find a way* to run the client-side scripts, so that the HTML can be generated completely before you can apply above XPath query against the HTML.